# How to know where an IP address belong to in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I have a bunch of logs to analyze, and there are many IP addresses. Some of them are ClusterIP and some of them are IP of pods, some - of nodes. But some are neither.

What other entities in Kubernetes are having an IP address?

And how can I quickly find an object that a certain IP belongs to?